# PyInstaller: EXE opens and closes

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller

As you can read in the headline, my .exe file doesn't do his job. After converting the .py file to an .exe file using PyInstaller, the file opens and closes a second later.
To create an .exe file I use:
`pyinstaller --onefile --icon="pong.ico" pong.py`
Any other files work fine. I use Python 3.8 and PyInstaller 3.6.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: what does your script supposed to do? If you have nothing blocking (asking for input, opening a gui etc.) The script will just run, finish and exit

Comment: Try to also run your `.exe` from your cmd so you can see any stdout or errors

Comment: Actually, it's a simple Pong Game. In earlier versions it works perfectly. I already tried to run the ```.exe``` in cmd. Then, the application opens and closes as expected and the cmd says: ```pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html```.